# How to manually set an array in Java?

Tags: java

How do you manually assign variables to an array?  I have a code fragment below.
I don't want to manually put `shortStraight[0] = "211100", shortStraight[1] = "021110"`, and so on.   Any help?

```
private String [] shortStraight;

    public Sample () {
        shorty = new String [12];
                shorty = {211100, 021110, 002111, 121100, 112100, 111200, 012110, 011210, 011120, 001211, 001121, 001112 } //this line doesn't work.
```

Any help?

Comment: Vote to close, this is too dang easy (google - "java initialize array of strings")

Comment: Um....which one is it?  Both your answers are different.

Comment: This is a legitimate question, even if in your opinion it's "too dang easy".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String[] shorty = {"211100", "021110", "002111", "121100", "112100", "111200", "012110", "011210", "011120", "001211", "001121", "001112"} ;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String[]   shorty = {"211100", "021110", "002111", "121100", "112100", "111200", "012110", "011210", "011120", "001211", "001121", "001112"} ;
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html